# Send pull request to GitHub

Tags: git, github

I have a repo on GitHub, but I do all my dev on local repos, and push to a local server when ready for server testing, and only push to GitHub when "live"

But what I want todo is, push to local server to test and rather than push to GitHub, I would rather send GitHub a pull request, to pull from my server

Is this actually possible, or so I need to push to a different GitHub branch and then do a pull request between branches, or setup a completely different GitHub repo, and then pull request from that one

I can't be the only one who works like this

Comment: Github allows pull requests inside single repo. So you can push into a separate branch and then create pull requests to you 'live' branch. Though, I don't think it's possible to perform pull request from a repo that is not hosted on Github.

Comment: Normally you would want to push the branch to your test server and when it's bug-free and tested well enough you would push it to GitHub from **YOUR** computer.

Answer (score 6):

`Pull Requests` are GitHub specific and can only be done within a repo or amongst repos in GitHub. It is not possible to setup a pull request from a local repo to one on GitHub.

Since you are using your repos as gates where you perform some valiadation, I would suggest having another repo on GitHub to which you push to and setup a pull request from that one to your "live" repo.

Comment: but i can do a pull request to a seperate repo
there is a command done with request-pull

e.g. git request-pull branch git://myserver/repo

Comment: @Keloran - Is that a question?

Comment: sorry needed to edit, enter did paste instead of newline like i was expecting since this is a textarea

Comment: http://wiki.koha-community.org/wiki/Sending_a_%22request_to_pull%22

example of how todo it, the problem is i dont seem to find how to send that to github, it seems that only works if you know the email of the person to send, which obviouslly then means htere is no audit-trail (one of hte main reasons i want to send the pull requests to github)

Comment: @Keloran - that is a different one, it is for patches, and works in a different way than how GitHub pull requests work, and doesn't help you with gitHub.

Comment: "which obviouslly then means htere is no audit-trail" -- that's not correct. Patch-by-mail workflows do work with git.  You can format patches out of local commits with `git format-patch -1`, send them via email, and apply them with `git am`.